# HttpRequest .setHeader Value to authorization failure in Java

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httprequest, java-9

There is a minor problem with ***jdk9.incubator.HttpRequest.Builder***

It seems like I cannot set headers with **authorization key**. Below code is for *APNs token authentication*.

```
request.setHeader("authorization", "bearer " + token);
```

I found that the word authorization is blocked in the source code

```
private static final Set<String> DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET = Set.of(
        "authorization", "connection", "cookie", "content-length",
        "date", "expect", "from", "host", "origin", "proxy-authorization",
        "referer", "user-agent", "upgrade", "via", "warning");

public static final Predicate<String>
    ALLOWED_HEADERS = header -> !Utils.DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET.contains(header);
```

**Is there a way to work around this?**

Comment: There's a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8194729) report against this.

Comment: @teppic Thanks for your reply! Does that mean there is no other way to work around this problem? It seems like CleverTap uses reflection to solve this problem, but reflection has a lot of issues regarding performance. If there is any other way to work around this problem, I just wanted to figure it out.